# Is there a C++ compiler flag in Visual Studio for int assumed?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++-6

I am trying to compile some old C++ in Visual Studio 2008 that compiles in Visual C++ 6. I am trying to deal with the errors through configuration changes and compiler instructions instead of changing the code.

In a lot of places in the code, there are variables and functions declared without a type. The compiler gives an error like "error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int".

For example:

```
class DLL WebPage
{
    private:
        char *ip_;
        char *port_;
        char *page_;

    public:
        WebPage();
        ~WebPage();
        get(char *ip,char *port,char *page); //<---This is the trouble maker
        char *ip(void);
        char *port(void);
        char *page(void);
};
```

Any way to get this to compile in a newer IDE?

Comment: No, just fix the code. Implicit int was removed already in the first C++ standard, C++98. I.e. it's never been in standard C++.

Comment: Much has happened in the evolution of HTML and CSS since the late 90's. So I'd suggest using some newer library anyway. If you want to consume modern web pages.

Comment: This is just one of hundreds of places in the code that has a similar problem. I will be updating and modernizing the code over the next few years, but for right now, I just need it to build as is.

Comment: With just a few hundred instances I think it would be more work to automate the fixups than just do it manually. Perhaps filter the compiler output on "implicit int" (or whatever) to get a list of locations.